# Why this scanf returns false?

Tags: c++, c

This scanf should always return true until I input none numeric input, but this scanf never executes while loop. Why?

Sample input:

```
10.0 5.0
Press [Enter] to close the terminal ...
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    float a, b;
    while ( scanf("%f %f", &a, &b) == 1 )
    {
        printf("%f\n", (a - b) / (a * b));
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`scanf` returns the number of items read, which in this case is 2.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` returns the number of items scanned successfully. In your case, it will return 2 to indicate success.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `scanf` returns `2` which is the number of items successfully read.

To keep reading till an `EOF` is encountered you can do:

```
while ( scanf("%f %f", &a, &b) != EOF )
```